# Can anyone help identify this painting? (Western, representative, c19-c21)

Tags: art

[image]This is the cover of a Penguin classic - the Love Letters of Keats. But I can't find the painting identified anywhere. Does anyone know it?

Comment: It sort of reminds me of Ophelia by Millais.

Comment: Could just be something Penguin commissioned for the cover for that one edition. Have you checked the inside of the cover and the first few pages? That's where I generally find info about the cover art, if its something well-known that needs to be acknowledged.

Comment: Did a search on Google reverse image search...no hit, except for the Keats book.

Answer (score 11):

The painting is quoted on the back cover of the book as "**So Bright and Delicate**", *oil on canvas, by* **Aaron Robinson**, *2009*.

Source: the Amazon preview of the book. (https://www.amazon.co.uk/So-Bright-Delicate-Letters-Classics/dp/0141442476#reader_0141442476)

His website, for anyone interested: http://aaronrobinson.net/

His wordpress blog: https://earthtorobinson.wordpress.com/

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: +1 well dug up, and also deserves another for the additional info.

Comment: @Orangesandlemons Appreciated.

Comment: @BradCarson You're welcome! Please mark this question as answered if you're satisfied with it :)